# Expectation over complex multiplication is multiplication of expectation

Tags: mathematical-statistics, random-variable, expected-value, complex-numbers

Suppose I have $\mathbb{E}\left[{\bf x} {\bf x}^H \right]$, where ${\bf x} \in \mathbb{C}^{N \times 1}$ is a random vector which has a uniform distribution, then can I say,

$\mathbb{E}\left[{\bf x} {\bf x}^H \right] = \mathbb{E}\left[{\bf x}\right] \mathbb{E}\left[{\bf x}^H \right] = \mathbb{E}\left[{\bf x}\right] \mathbb{E}\left[{\bf x} \right]^H $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't encountered complex RVs before, but anything that holds for them should also hold for *real* RVs as real numbers are also complex. So, no, you can't. For simplicity consider real $\mathbf{x}$, in which hermitian is actually transposing. What you propose is this:
$$\operatorname{var}(\mathbf{x})=E[\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^T]-E[\mathbf{x}]\underbrace{E[\mathbf{x}^T]}_{E[\mathbf{x}]^T}=\mathbf{0}$$

This means the covariance matrix is always $0$, which is wrong.